# Proper way to handle file open and file close Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

Please see this implementation:

```
@staticmethod
    def read_json_file__(file):
        reports = []
        try:
            with open(file) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                for d in data:
                    # Do my stuff...
            try:
                json_file.close()
            except IOError as ex:
                raise Exception(ex)
            return reports
        except FileNotFoundError as ex:
            raise Exception('File \'{f}\' does not exist.'.format(f=ex.filename))
        except Exception:
            raise
```

I try to find the way to handle `Exceptions` so I handle file open `Exception` (`FileNotFoundError`) and file close `Exception` (`IOError`) and also add Generic `Exception` and raise it to caller method.
Is this correct way to handle `Exception` ?

Comment: Handling exceptions by raising a less specific or even the same exception without doing any handling is usually not very helpful.

Comment: There is no benefit in handling the exceptions the way you do, as explained by @KlausD. And no need to close the file when using `with` context manager. And on more general level - there is also `finally` block of the `try/except/else/finally` that will be executed always at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `with open(file) as json_file`, you do not need to close, but if you use `json_file = open(file)` you do need to close it (with `json_file.close()`).

Comment: So i can just remove this close line ?

Comment: @DanRaz, please mark my answer as the correct one (checkmark)